# SVG onhover event on sides of polygon

Tags: html, svg

I created a hexagon using SVG polygon. Now, I want to attach onhover event on sides of hexagon. Below is how I created SVG element.

```
<svg width="500" height="500" id="svgTry">
<polygon id="polySvg" points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" fill="transparent" stroke="rgb(249, 249, 249)" stroke-width="20" />
</svg>
```

I tried

```
$('#polySvg').on("mouseenter",function(){
this.style['stroke-width'] = 20;
console.log("clicked");
});
$('#polySvg').on("mouseleave",function(){
this.style['stroke-width'] = 30;
console.log("clicked");
});
```

This is for the whole polygon. Can we create same kind of onhover event on each sides of hexagon?

Answer (score 2):

You need to recreate your polygon as six separate sides.  Or, more accurately, twelve separate sides, since there are two different stroke widths. And you'll probably want them to be trapezoid-shaped to account for the bevelled angles where they join.

That's assuming that you don't want to add code to work out which size of the polygon you are closest to, and modify the SVG accordingly.  Which is a lot of unnecessary work.

**Update**

There are a few ways to do what you want.  Here is one way that is perhaps a simpler approach:

1. We create a triangular clipping path for each of the six sides.

   Below is the hexagon which has had a clip path applied.  The red triangle shows where the clip path is.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" id="svgTry">

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cp1">
      <polygon points="150,150, 150,0, 285,75"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0"
           fill="transparent" stroke="rgb(49, 249, 249)" stroke-width="20"
           clip-path="url(#cp1)"/>

  <polygon points="150,150, 150,0, 285,75" fill="red" opacity="0.2"/>

</svg>
```

2. Now if we create five more clipping paths - one matching each of the other five sides.  We add five more copies of the hexagon, each with one of the new clip paths applied.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" id="svgTry">

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cp1">
      <polygon points="150,150, 150,0, 285,75"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cp2">
      <polygon points="150,150, 285,75, 285,225"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cp3">
      <polygon points="150,150, 285,225, 150,300"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cp4">
      <polygon points="150,150, 150,300, 15,225"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cp5">
      <polygon points="150,150, 15,225, 15,75"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cp6">
      <polygon points="150,150, 15,75, 150,0"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g id="sides" fill="transparent" stroke="rgb(49, 249, 249)" stroke-width="20">
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp1)"/>
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp2)"/>
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp3)"/>
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp4)"/>
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp5)"/>
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp6)"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

3. We now have a hexgon again. But each of the sides can be targetted with a hover rule to change its stroke width.

```css
#sides polygon:hover {
  stroke-width: 40;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" id="svgTry">

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cp1">
      <polygon points="150,150, 150,0, 285,75"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cp2">
      <polygon points="150,150, 285,75, 285,225"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cp3">
      <polygon points="150,150, 285,225, 150,300"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cp4">
      <polygon points="150,150, 150,300, 15,225"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cp5">
      <polygon points="150,150, 15,225, 15,75"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="cp6">
      <polygon points="150,150, 15,75, 150,0"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g id="sides" fill="transparent" stroke="rgb(49, 249, 249)" stroke-width="20">
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp1)"/>
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp2)"/>
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp3)"/>
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp4)"/>
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp5)"/>
    <polygon points="150,0 285,75 285,225 150,300 15,225 15,75 150,0" clip-path="url(#cp6)"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Is this close to what you want?

Note for simplicity I've constructed the clip paths using the same coordinates as the hexagon.  However that means that the outside half of the stroke is being clipped off.  So we are only seeing half the line.  That's why when you hover, the stroke only gets thicker on the inside.  If you want to fix that, you will need to update the clip triangles so that they are extend past the outside of the hexagon a little bit.

Comment: I am now trying to create hexagon using 6 paths. Its not clear as in polygon. Its generating gaps between each path I don't know how to fill the gap between them. For Ex;-  `<path d="M150,0L285,75C" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:20" ></path>
<path d="M285,75L285,225" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:20" ></path>`  this creates a triangular gap between 2 paths.

Comment: Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You won't be able to do it with lines. That's why I said you will have to create a filled [trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid) shape for each of your sides.